# mockito when() is not available

Tags: mockito, spring-boot-actuator

I want to mock userRepository using when() method but the method itself is not available
The package import static org.mockito.Mockito.when is not available in the jar downloaded by Spring boot

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.bapan</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringBoot-Mockito</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

    /**
 * 
 */
package org.bapan.api.test;

import org.bapan.repository.UserRepository;
import org.bapan.service.UserService;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

/**
 * 
 *
 */
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringBootApiTest {
    /**
     * 
     */
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    /**
     * 
     */
    @MockBean
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void getAllUsers() {
        //when(userRepository.findAll()).thenReturn();
    }

}
```

When method it self is not present.
In which jar I can find the when method()?
Which exact dependencies need to be added to get the when method

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`mvnrepo page`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.1.2.RELEASE), `spring-boot-starter-parent` includes `mockito-core 2.23.4`.
As usual it should be found in that jar.

[`Javadoc`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.4/org/mockito/Mockito.html) of the Mockito class Version `2.23.4`.

If you can't resolve any mockito related class in your testsource directory, you might need to properly configure maven (or your project) to tell it which the `testSourceDirectory` is (under the build section / see [`link`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Build_Element)).

If that does not help check the jar from your classpath, maybe its broken and you need to force maven to redownload it.

(Note: I am not seeing an import in your file, but I guess you removed it, because it was not working)